# node js can't process sns event message content

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am trying to get content from Message in SNS event in node js lambda project

here is a code for processing message

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
console.log('Message received from SNS:', message); 

message.Events.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);

   });
};
```

sample event:

```
{ 
 "Records": 
  [ 
    { 
     "EventSource": "aws:sns",
     "EventVersion": "1.0",
     "EventSubscriptionArn": "",
     "Sns": 
       { 
         "Type": "Notification",
         "MessageId": "bc86f105-c320",
         "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ewerwrewrw",
         "Subject": "dwqweq23234",
         "Message": 
           {
           "Events":
             [
               {"EventTimestamp":"2018-03-16T10:51:22Z"},
               {"EventTimestamp":"2018-03-16T10:51:22Z"}
             ],
            "EventDocVersion":"2014-08-15"
           },
          "Timestamp": "2018-03-16T10:51:22.691Z",
          "SignatureVersion": "1",
          "Signature": "",
          "SigningCertUrl": "",
          "UnsubscribeUrl": "",
          "MessageAttributes": {} 
      } 
    } 
  ]
 }
```

This is what I get in CloudWatch logs:

> Message received from SNS:
>      {
>                  "Events":
>                    [
>                      {"EventTimestamp":"2018-03-16T10:51:22Z"},
>                      {"EventTimestamp":"2018-03-16T10:51:22Z"}
>                    ],
>                   "EventDocVersion":"2014-08-15"
>      }
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
>   at exports.handler

Why I am not being able to parse 'Events' inside message object in event?

Comment: Because `message.Events` is undefined.

Comment: I understood that. but why I can't parse Events inside message. that's my questions

Comment: Have you tried console logging `message` to see you have a property called `Events`? How are you calling your function?

Comment: @Dan yes. I did this: var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message; console.log('Message received from SNS:', message); You can see console.log result in question. it gives: Message received from SNS:  { "Events": [ {"EventTimestamp":"2018-03-16T10:51:22Z"}, {"EventTimestamp":"2018-03-16T10:51:22Z"} ], "EventDocVersion":"2014-08-15" }

Comment: Is not possible, you need to be sure that there aren't any others part of your code assigning value different values to that variable.

Comment: Try printing `console.log(message.Events)`

Comment: @Ele console.log(message.Events) prints undefined

Comment: How are you calling your function? Is it through API Gateway????

Comment: @Dan no that's SNS

Comment: Try to json parse  from string to object  !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

worked after I fixed to this:

```
var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;

var msgJson = JSON.parse(message);

msgJson["Events"].forEach(element => { .....
```

Comment: Same problem, this worked for me. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

try **message["Events"].forEach** instead of message.Events may work and check weather property exists using.Actually  **message.Events** this should work if you get the same object in console as you have mentioned but you can avoid error at least by checking the property.
----Edit----**if(message && message.hasOwnProperty('Events'))**

```
if(message && message.hasOwnProperty('Events')){
   message.Events.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);

   });
}
```

I think the message that you are getting is blank first try printing that because I tried below in browser worked properly:

```
var obj={ 
 "Records": 
  [ 
    { 
     "EventSource": "aws:sns",
     "EventVersion": "1.0",
     "EventSubscriptionArn": "",
     "Sns": 
       { 
         "Type": "Notification",
         "MessageId": "bc86f105-c320",
         "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ewerwrewrw",
         "Subject": "dwqweq23234",
         "Message": 
           {
           "Events":
             [
               {"EventTimestamp":"2018-03-16T10:51:22Z"},
               {"EventTimestamp":"2018-03-16T10:51:22Z"}
             ],
            "EventDocVersion":"2014-08-15"
           },
          "Timestamp": "2018-03-16T10:51:22.691Z",
          "SignatureVersion": "1",
          "Signature": "",
          "SigningCertUrl": "",
          "UnsubscribeUrl": "",
          "MessageAttributes": {} 
      } 
    } 
  ]
 };
var fun1 = function(event, context, callback){

var message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
console.log('Message received from SNS:', message); 
console.log("starting")
message["Events"].forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);

   });
};
fun1(obj,'',function(){console.log("uu")})
```